# Determining how to quickly classify columns in huge datasets as factors

Tags: r, apply, r-caret, categorical-data, data-cleaning

No good example here since my datasets that I am working with are huge.

But if I have a 200,300something column dataset I want to have some sort of rule to quickly classify and convert some of these columns to factors.  Is there some quick R code to do it?

Reason being I don't have time to go column by column to completely understand or interpret data, but if I see there are just unique 4 values out 5000 rows, I assume that this is categorical data.

Anyone have any quick code snippets or ways to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `df` refers to your dataframe:

```
## Find all columns with less than 5 unique values
cols <- apply(df, 2, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) < 5

## Convert columns with less than 5 unique values to factor
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], factor)
```